# including customer/wishlist into customer/account/index

Tags: blocks, magento-1, wishlist

In **customer->account->index** I currently have the following Child Html (`customer.account.dashboard.extra`, `info`, `address`). My idea is to include other child html into that page to enhance current customer view when they log into the system and are redirected to their account info.

I copied the information from `wishlist.xml`:

```
<block type="wishlist/customer_wishlist" name="customer.wishlist" template="wishlist/view.phtml">
    <block type="wishlist/customer_wishlist_items" name="customer.wishlist.items" as="items" template="wishlist/item/list.phtml">
        <block type="wishlist/customer_wishlist_item_column_image" name="customer.wishlist.item.image" template="wishlist/item/column/image.phtml" />
        <block type="wishlist/customer_wishlist_item_column_comment" name="customer.wishlist.item.info" template="wishlist/item/column/info.phtml">
            <action method="setTitle" translate="title">
                <title>Product Details and Comment</title>
            </action>
        </block>
        <block type="wishlist/customer_wishlist_item_column_cart" name="customer.wishlist.item.cart" template="wishlist/item/column/cart.phtml">
            <action method="setTitle" translate="title">
                <title>Add to Cart</title>
            </action>
            <block type="wishlist/customer_wishlist_item_options" name="customer.wishlist.item.options" />
        </block>
        <block type="wishlist/customer_wishlist_item_column_remove" name="customer.wishlist.item.remove" template="wishlist/item/column/remove.phtml" />
    </block>
    <block type="core/text_list" name="customer.wishlist.buttons" as="control_buttons">
        <block type="wishlist/customer_wishlist_button" name="customer.wishlist.button.share" template="wishlist/button/share.phtml" />
        <block type="wishlist/customer_wishlist_button" name="customer.wishlist.button.toCart" template="wishlist/button/tocart.phtml" />
        <block type="wishlist/customer_wishlist_button" name="customer.wishlist.button.update" template="wishlist/button/update.phtml" />
    </block>
</block>
```

and include that information into `local.xml` inside `<customer_account_index translate="label">`

then I placed `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('customer') ?>` inside `customer/account/dashboard.phtml`

But no results are displayed. My main idea is to know which steps do I have to follow to include particular codes into other pages. (like: modify xml, include in phtml.., etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that your block `customer.wishlist` is included in `local.xml` under the correct layout handle (`customer_account_index`). Then attach your wishlist block to the dashboard block:

```
<customer_account_index>
    <reference name="customer_account_dashboard">
        <block type="wishlist/customer_wishlist" as="wishlist" name="customer.wishlist" template="wishlist/view.phtml">
            <!-- rest of your imported layout XML here -->
        </block>
    </reference>
</customer_account_index>
```

This will make it accessible in the template when you call for it. Then, render it with:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('wishlist'); ?>
```

I call for `wishlist` because that's the alias (`as`) defined in the wishlist block node.

Comment: You're welcome. When struggling with layout XML, one of my favorite resources for learning about it is a book by Alan Storm called "No-Frills Magento Layout" -- worth a read.

Comment: i bought commerce bug extension, i will check the book, thanks!